# Issue with Jenkins Serer Upgarde

Tags: jenkins

we have upgraded jenkins. war to the latest version and we can see the latest version in Jenkins console as well.
But the issue is when we open add/or remove programs from control panel it is still pointing to the old version. Please let me know what can be done to resolve the issue.

Comment: How did you _initially_ install Jenkins? What is the current version?

Comment: it was installed as an windows service. We have placed new war file now.

Comment: version in jenkins home page is 2.204.1 and in add/or remove programs still it is showing 2.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. This will have no effect on your set up. Though `Add or remove programs` will show the earlier version that you installed but whenever you decide to *uninstall* it, it's going to *uninstall* whichever version will be present in your Jenkins installation directory.

Note: What i have observed is that it actually removes the Windows service when it uninstalls but leaves the Jenkins installation directory structure intact.